# Handling not found in Ebean and Dropwizard

Tags: java, jersey, ebean, dropwizard

I have the following code in the `resources`:

```
@GET
@Timed
@Path("/{username}")
public Object findUserByUsername(@PathParam("username") String username){
    User user = Ebean.find(User.class)
            .setDisableLazyLoading(true)
            .where()
            .eq("username", username)
            .findUnique();
    if(user != null) {
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.OK)
                .entity(Ebean.json().toJson(user))
                .build();
    }else{
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)
                .build();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to handle the errors when it happens on Ebean, like in this case, I want to build a custom response if there is no `User` with the given `username`. But when `Ebean.find()` don't find a matching data, it already returns a default error page. How can I customize this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the default page to show up, just have to provide an `.entity()` to the `Response` with the error code and it will replace the default page with the model json that is inside `.entity()`.